# javascript function set Onclick event

Tags: javascript, html

I need to set button onclick event for this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $.bootstrapGrowl("This Product Information Already Exist", { 
            type: "success",
            align: "right"
        });
    }, 1000);
});
</script>
```

Here this is a function now I need press the button when run this function.
plz. help...

Comment: This is very basic JavaScript/jQuery. What have you tried?

Comment: can you tell you i do this? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you mean on button click event this function should execute ??

```
<script>
$("#btn").click(fucntion(){
setTimeout(function() {
        $.bootstrapGrowl("This Product Information Already Exist", { 
            type: "success",
            align: "right"
        });
    }, 1000);
});
</script>
```

Comment: yes.. i tried like this..
<button type="submit" class="btn blue" name="sub" id="btn">
<br>
but it's not working